# joomla website didn't work well in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, joomla2.5

I work with this joomla 2.5 template http://www.linelab.org/demo-templates-joomla/index.php?template=orangelab, after modifiying it, it doesn't work with firefox, i tested it in chrome and it worked well, i checked  the css file; it is located before the last line in the header.

```
<link media="screen,projection" type="text/css" href="/templates/orangelab/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

i have checked

```
<div id="socialinks>
```

in firebug and i don't find socialinks in the style tab in the right although i have #socialinks in  /templates/orangelab/css/styles.css

if any one could help, i would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, it was an error in the CSS file that prevented the other CSS properties to load.

Comment: please mark your question as answered by using the arrow next to the answer on the left.

Comment: you mean to vote my answer?

Comment: Not the arrow... the check-mark.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in `<div id="socialinks>`
Use `<div id="socialinks">` instead

Comment: it is a typo, i used it correcty in my template file